# Oracle inner join headache oci_execute(): ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to accomplish an inner join (Oracle calls them equijoins) with two tables and I'm just missing something because it's different than MySQL inner joins.  I'm also new to PHP (coming from Lasso) so I'm trying to be strict with my syntax for my own sanity.  I've looked at all the other posts about this error but they haven't helped.

Connecting to an Oracle 12c database with PHP 5.5.29, OCI8 is installed and verified in php info page.

[Oracle's explanation of inner joins](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm#TGSQL95239)

$login is plaintext and $pw is hashed before this snippet:

```
// separate the login types by the "_" character
if (strpos($login, "_") == true) {
    $fieldname = 'web_password_hash';
    $dynfield = 'web_id';
    $dynfield1 = 's.web_id';
} else {
    $fieldname = 'student_web_password_hash';
    $dynfield = 'student_web_id';
    $dynfield1 = 's.student_web_id';
}

$schoolid = '(pcs.schoolid=4 OR pcs.schoolid=5)';

// search custom table for a field with the correct password (parent/student)
$dbc = oci_connect($psusername, $pspassword, $psconnection);

if(!$dbc) {
    echo "Oracle Not connected";
} else {

$stmt = oci_parse($dbc, 'SELECT pcs.student_number AS snumber, :dynfield1 AS loginid, s.ID AS sid, s.family_ident AS famid, s.firstname AS fname, s.last_name AS lname, s.grade_level AS gradelevel 
    FROM pvsis_custom_students pcs, students s 
        WHERE pcs.student_number=s.student_number 
            AND :schoolid 
            AND pcs.field_name=:fieldname 
            AND pcs.string_value=:pw 
            AND s.enroll_status=0;');

// bind parameters to prevent SQL injection         
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':dynfield1', $dynfield1);          
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':fieldname', $fieldname);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':schoolid', $schoolid);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':pw', $pw);

// execute statement
oci_execute($stmt);
```

The error I then get is: **Warning:** oci_execute(): ORA-00920: invalid relational operator in */path/to/file line XXX*

Comment: You need to select `s.student_number`.

Comment: Okay. Have two different select for the two different purposes. Also, please include the _actual_ select that gets executed and throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind the name of the fields the way you're doing it here. You'll need to build the query dynamically:

```
$stmt = oci_parse($dbc, 'SELECT pcs.student_number AS snumber, ' . $dynfield1 . ' AS loginid, s.ID AS sid, s.family_ident AS famid, s.firstname AS fname, s.last_name AS lname, s.grade_level AS gradelevel 
    FROM pvsis_custom_students pcs, students s 
        WHERE pcs.student_number=s.student_number 
            AND ' . $schoolid . '
            AND pcs.field_name=' . $fieldname . '
            AND pcs.string_value=:pw 
            AND s.enroll_status=0;');
```

Remove the `bind_by_name` calls for `:dynfield1`, `:fieldname`, and `:schoolid`.

Best of luck.

Comment: I thought binding was the best way to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: You do need to be concerned about that when you're accepting input from something like a user-entered value. In this case, however, your values are all string constants in your routine so injection isn't a possibility. More to the point, you can't bind column names - it just won't work. You can bind *values*, but not column names, table names, bits-and-pieces of the where clause, etc.

Comment: The :pw field, aka password, which you missed is a user input field.

Comment: If you'll notice, I left it as a bound value rather than concatenating it into the SQL query, because I couldn't determine that it was safe to concatenate - also because in this case the binding is fine, as what's being bound is a value rather than a field name. Also note that I did not say to remove the `bind_by_name` for `:pw`. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks Bob.  I'm learning all of these PHP nuances as I go :)